# SPListItem dont Add new Item

Tags: splistitem, splist

```
class Vote
    {
        public static void DoneVote(DataTable table)
        {
            string siteUrl = "...";    
            try
            {                   
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                        {
                            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");
                            if (list != null) {
                                SPListItem itemToAdd = list.AddItem();
                                itemToAdd["Title"] = "DA0000";
                                itemToAdd["IdProject"] = "10";
                                itemToAdd["DateOf"] = DateTime.Today;
                                itemToAdd["Type"] = "1";
                                itemToAdd["Project"] = "1";
                                itemToAdd.Update();
                            }
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log errors
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

And I am making call like below:

```
Vote.DoneVote(table);
```

I havn't got any error, but `itemToAdd` not adding in `ListName`.
When I debug it I see, what `table` has correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding  `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` before `for loop` and then after `for loop` add `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;`

So the code will be:

```
 try
            {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {

                        if (list != null) {
                            SPListItem itemToAdd = list.AddItem();
                            itemToAdd["Title"] = "DA0000";
                            itemToAdd["IdProject"] = "10";
                            itemToAdd["DateOf"] = DateTime.Today;
                            itemToAdd["Type"] = "1";
                            itemToAdd["Project"] = "1";
                            itemToAdd.Update();
                        }
                    }
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log errors
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not update column ID as you have done in your code

Remove this line `itemToAdd["ID"] = "10";` from your code

Entire code will be

```
class Vote
{
    public static void DoneVote(DataTable table)
    {
        string siteUrl = "...";
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");
                        if (list != null) {
                            SPListItem itemToAdd = list.AddItem();
                            itemToAdd["Title"] = "DA0000";
                            itemToAdd["DateOf"] = DateTime.Today;
                            itemToAdd["Type"] = "1";
                            itemToAdd["Project"] = "1";
                            itemToAdd.Update();
                            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(itemToAdd["ID"]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log errors
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for answer, but it doesn't work

Comment: debug the entire code line by line and see where it breaks or throws exception

Comment: I do it, but i haven't any breaks or throw exception. Simple empty list.

Comment: Its weird. Have you tried updated code? it should print the newly created ItemdID. While debugging check list.Items.Count once list object is created & not null.

Comment: it created and not null.

Comment: Can you write in more detail? What it created and not null, list object or item ?? If list object.. then what is "list.Items.Count" returning???

Comment: Also make sure your list view don't have any filters in it. Those may be preventing items to display.

Comment: @PS say right way, but I thankful for you try fix my problem